# Update html 'permanenlty' with no database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I made a website for crowd-funding. I know that we should have used a platform for this. (other issues determined us not to)

The page that I have created has no database behind.
What I am trying to do is create some kind of hidden form that updates the sum that was raised so far.

I am not a very technical person but I do know that modifications made through javascript / jQuery ar usually temporary.

But, since scripts like website visit counters do exist I am wondering and appealing to the collective wisdom of this community:

Is there a way to update an attribute of a html element through some kind of hidden form without a database behind?

Perhaps writing to a .json file and updating the attribute from the data?

(I need to do this today as I will not be at the office during the campaign and it is very hard for a person that has no technical skills to do it... not that hard, but still, not user friendly.)

Comment: You need to use server side script like php to do this.

Comment: However you're not restricted to web languages like php if you don't mind your page not being updated on demand : you could use python, java, sed or whatever to update the page at regular interval then let a basic web server serve the modified version

Comment: What is today? Current time in Samoa is 00:43 1st Dec, 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display variable data, you need to get these data *somewhere*.

Do you have write access to your server file system?
What service level do you expect during data manipulation? Does it suffice if you just go and upload modified file every time manually?

What about embed in your Web page an IMG and then upload it with always the same name and different content?

There *is* a database even behind "dummy" hit counters, no magic.

Comment: I already have angular and some code that pulls data out of .json files. I think I'll "train" someone to edit that file and update the attribute through angular. It seems this would be the easiest temporary solution.